# Google script copy data from a sheet to another in efficent way

Tags: google-apps-script

I have to copy data from one spreadsheet to another.
On the source I have a sheet with columns **DataName** and **DataID**

I need to copy **DataName** column in SSdest sheet('Data'), DataID in SSdest sheet('ID').

I can do it in several ways, but I need to be time effective due to a big load of data. I pick data using `Data = Source.getDataRange().getValues()`

I can paste in the correct way using a for loop with `setvalue()` but is time-consuming. Is there a way to paste only one column from getValues data?

Comment: You can use `.setValues()` and provide the array you've acquired earlier through `.getValues()`. No need for a for loop.

Comment: If you only want to paste one column then change the range so that you only get one column.

Comment: Thank's for reply, 
Data = getDataRange().getValues() is containing more than one column, I need to paste only one of those.

Comment: .. how to tell that I want to setValue only column 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Casper told you, you can use `range.getValues()` to get a multidimensional array then use `range.setValues()`. You only need to set the range to one column to get all the datas wanted as so : `sheet.getRange(rowNumber, columnNumber, numberOfRows).getValues()`.

One other solution would be to select all the datas with `getDataRange()`, then programatically using javascript create a new array you will then add using `setValues(array)`

Comment: ok so I have to read data from spreadsheet two times instead to access file one time to read all data.
now is still working like this, so is not possible to do better.
Thank's
var NomiClassi = FoglioClassi.getRange(2,1,FoglioClassi.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var IDClassi = FoglioClassi.getRange(2,4,FoglioClassi.getLastRow(),1).getDisplayValues();

Comment: `code`
//read all data
var Data = ssource.getDataRange().getValues;
// Split them in two array
var Data1 = new Array;
var Data2 = new Array;
for (i in Data) {
Data1.push(Data[i,1]);
Data2.push(Data[i,4]);
}
// write them all
sdest1.getRange(1,1,Data1.length).setValues(Data1);
sdest2.getRange(1,1,Data2.length).setValues(Data1);
`code`
Right?
Just to test depending on the dimension of data if is more time consuming open the sheet two time or split with for loop.
Good idea anyway,

Comment: how can I do that? ... I'm very newbe

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AhhtrnYwjYUeUh3WISRq39X-KntzG-Fw9CsXoyo7YUM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm leaving work, I'll be back on wednesday
Thank's for helping